# Display code with notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm using NOTEPAD++ as my editor

I opened CSS file and saw that the editor present all the css code in 1 line

How can I return it to be in multi lines?

Thanks

Comment: why you don't try to use a better editor? There are many on the net that are free and full of functions

Comment: I writing with PHP. Can you recommended?

Comment: You can reformat your CSS [here](http://www.codebeautifier.com/). Then NotePad++ should display it properly.

Comment: eclipse for php is a good start

Comment: @Gianmarco Notepad++ is an excellent code editor.

Comment: @Kolink: Agreed, very flexible and extensible code editor.

Answer (score 3):

It might be that Notepad++ is having trouble recognising what kind of line ending your file is using.

Click View => Show Symbol => End of Line, and this should make visible some characters where the newlines should be:

If you see just [CR], then your file is using Old Mac format.
Just [LF] is UNIX/OSX format.
[CR][LF] is DOS/Windows format.

Then go to Edit => EOL Conversion and select the appropriate item from the list. This should fix your line ending problems.